# Unable to load script on puppeteer AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, puppeteer

Im trying to add an external javascript file to puppeteer on Lambda.

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
const browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
  ....
});

const webPage = await browser.newPage();
await webPage.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0 });
await webPage.addScriptTag({
   url: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`,
});
```

But unable to load the script

```
ERROR   Error: Loading script from https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js failed
at DOMWorld.addScriptTag (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/DOMWorld.js:171:23)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
at async I (/var/task/src/functions/preparePages/handler.js:20:3689)
at async Runtime.E [as handler] (/var/task/src/functions/preparePages/handler.js:20:5400)
```